# Postpone RadioButton change

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent, code-behind

I'm looking for possibility to block switching `RadioButton`'s, but still catch `Click` event. Unfortunatelly using `Enabled=false` or `IsHitTestVisible=false` properties prevent `Click` event.

What I want to achieve is: 
1. User clicks `RadioButton`. 
2. From `Click` event some method is called with handler passed as argument but active `RadioButton` is yet unchanged. 
3. When handler is called, depending on the result I want to switch `RadioButton` or not.

Comment: you would like to take delegate as parameter, right? And where are they(delegates) keeping: in some private collection or in Tag property or in some meta-info of each RadioButton?

Comment: To be more precise I call C++\CLI method, taking as argument delegate. I give it as an argument method from my C# class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created for you simple example.

Do not forget take from `NuGet` the `Prism` package.

I create three `RadioButton`'s and set for they `Func<bool>` from some ViewModel. After `PreviewMouseDown` event firing, I invoke current delegate, which is `Func<bool>` from `Tag` property.

ViewModel:

```
namespace PostponeRadioButtonChange.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;

    public class MainWindow : BindableBase
    {
        private List<Func<bool>> rbHandlers;

        private string comment;

        public List<Func<bool>> RbHandlers
        {
            get { return this.rbHandlers; }
            private set { this.SetProperty(ref this.rbHandlers, value); }
        }

        public string Comment
        {
            get { return this.comment; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this.comment, value); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.RbHandlers = new List<Func<bool>>
            {
                () =>
                    {
                        this.Comment = "First RadioButton clicked";
                        return false;    // Here must be your condition for checking
                    },
                () =>
                    {
                        this.Comment = "Second RadioButton clicked";
                        return false;
                    },
                () =>
                    {
                        this.Comment = "Third RadioButton clicked";
                        return true;   // For example, third not checked after click
                    }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Content of View(designer);

```
<StackPanel>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Comment, Mode=OneWay}"/>

    <RadioButton Content="First"
                 PreviewMouseDown="RadioButtonMouseDown"
                 Tag="{Binding Path=RbHandlers[0], Mode=OneTime}"/>

    <RadioButton Content="Second"
                 PreviewMouseDown="RadioButtonMouseDown"
                 Tag="{Binding Path=RbHandlers[1], Mode=OneTime}"/>

    <RadioButton Content="Third"
                 PreviewMouseDown="RadioButtonMouseDown"
                 Tag="{Binding Path=RbHandlers[2], Mode=OneTime}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

View(code-behind):

```
namespace PostponeRadioButtonChange
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    using VM = PostponeRadioButtonChange.Model;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new VM.MainWindow();
        }

        private void RadioButtonMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var rb = (sender as RadioButton);

            if (rb == null)
                throw new InvalidCastException("RadioButtonMouseDown only for RadioButton's");

            e.Handled = (rb.Tag as Func<bool>)?.Invoke() ?? false;
        }
    }
}
```

It is not good for the final solution, but as an example should help you. You can also create a `Command` in VM instead of an event handler.

I hope, it will help you)

Comment: Thank you, it is far more than I needed, but very educative especially lambda array. Just changing my event to `PreviewMouseDown` from `Click` and then using `e.Handled = true' did the job. I already had a handler and all the logic written switching those radio buttons.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you)

Answer (score 2):

You should handle MouseDown event on radio button and then it would prevent from tunneling down to set the radio button as checked.

```
static void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     // if some logic...
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: It is will not work. 
Firstly, in wpf RadioButton mouse click event is name like MouseDown or PreviewMouseDown.
Secondly, in this case you must use PreviewMouseDown. In MouseDown  e.Handled=true will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using bindings you could put the call inside the setter, like this:

**xaml**

```
<RadioButton Content="radiobutton" IsChecked="{Binding TestRadio, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**code**

```
    private bool _testRadio;
    public bool TestRadio
    {
        get { return _testRadio; }
        set { value = testradiohandler(); SetProperty(ref _testRadio, value); }
    }
    private bool testradiohandler()
    {
        return new Random().NextDouble() >= 0.5;
    }
```